# Adding new transient field to existing @Enity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, transient

I have entity like this

```
@Entity
class Dates{

        @Column(name="day");
        private String day;


        @Column(name="year");
        private String year;

        //getters and setters


        //this is I want to have like dateAndyear=day+"-"+year or even create date object based on day and year
        private String dateAndyear;


}
```

I want to have this field dateAndyear internally in entity automatically set when entity is created. And after that I want to use this field in "where" clause of Criteria API.

Comment: would you like to elaborate with some code?

Comment: my final goal is to create Date object from day and year field and use "between" function in Criteria Builder to search entities

Comment: Why does your database have `day` and `year` columns, and more importantly why are they `Strings`? You should concentrate on fixing the design instead of trying to work around the problems caused by it.

Comment: There is a clear business reason for this. It's not a subject of this issue. This is distributed system with the data exchanging by ETL over DBs and that is out of my controll

Comment: You don't have to tell me fairy tales. I've heard enough "business reasons" to know what that means. If your db supports computed columns you could try that (or create a trigger for it). If you can't touch the db, then you're going to have to forget your plan of using that in a criteria query and come up with something else.

Comment: yeah. You might be right with this "business reasons". I can't touch the db now, so I will implement java filtering for the result list. Thank you for hints @Kayaman

Answer (score 1):

Transient fields are not part of serialization process and not persisted in databse hence cannot be used in criteria api as where clause.
But you can always intialize them using constructor while creation, hibernate internally would never initialize them.

Comment: There is no way to do sth like ?  predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.<Date>get("dateAndyear"), date));  ?

Comment: Since a transient field is not present in the database, and since a Criteria query executes in the database, do you really need to ask?

Comment: Puneet/Billy are correct, transient can't be used in queries.  You can only use the fields that exist in the DB, as queries are executed there.